# Select com expressão "diferente de" com duas condições

Tags: sql, query, select, firebird

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de fazer um `select` usando um `where` para um campo com o parâmetro diferente de `< >`, sendo que o mesmo tenha dois ou mais itens.

Para facilitar segue exemplo:

```
select * from TAB_DESPESAS where cd_item <> '0' order by cd_processo;
```

Para esta consulta tenho mais de um código para o campo `cd_item`, o que no caso, seria uma especie de lista (códigos: 0, 2, 20 e 21). Sendo assim, gostaria de trazer neste consulta todos os demais itens, exceto os itens da lista.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use o `NOT IN`

```
select * from TAB_DESPESAS where cd_item NOT IN ('0','2','20','21') order by cd_processo;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, @LINQ.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte comando:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE COD_STATUS NOT IN ('2','10','5')
```